# Sharepoint 2007 Title Column with Default View

Tags: c#, sharepoint, sharepoint-2007

I have a problem with accessing Title column from List.

I am building WebPart, which access the list with **deault view**.

Code looks like this (handling list item):

```
    var i = new MenuItem();
    try
    {
        i.Title = item.GetFormattedValue("ShortTitle");
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(i.Title))
        {
            i.Title = item.Title;
        }
        object urlValue = item["DestinationUrl"];
        string url = "";
        if (urlValue != null)
        {
            var value = new SPFieldUrlValue(urlValue.ToString());
            i.Url = value.Url;
        }
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        ErrorHandling.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("Your list must contain ShortTitle, Title and DestinationUrl columns"));

        ErrorHandling.Visible = true;
        return;
    }

    MenuItems.Add(i);
```

This code leads to exception:

```
Value does not fall within the expected range.
```

Problem exists in line `i.Title = item.Title;`. When i remove this line, exception is not raised.

Any advice about this error?

BTW. When I am not using list.DefaultView, everythink works correctly

Answer (score 0):

I think your Default View does not contains the title field.
Try to include the Title field in your Default View, or try to use list.Items instead of list.DefaultView.